# Display an image from an HTTP Get with basic authorization in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image, http, xmlhttprequest

I have a server that can return image raw data with a header of content-type:image/jpeg. I can use a java HTTPRequest to display the image by parsing the raw data into an image, but I want to do the same thing in a website. The call looks something like

https://mysite:9999/Get/Capture?1920x1080.

It generates the image from a camera and returns the data. I want to be able to display the returned image in an html  tag, is it possible to parse that out and generate an image in javascript? There are similar questions, but most involve getting images from actual image links ie example.com/test.jpg which can be passed in as the source.

I have a few calls to the same server for text information in the form of XMLHTTPRequests, is the same possible here? This is not using a react/angular framework, all vanilla javascript. The goal is for a clickable button to get the image and display it, but those details are less important than actually parsing raw image data from an HTTP GET.

Comment: What happens when you set this URL to the source of an `<img src="https://mysite:9999/Get/Capture?1920x1080" />` tag? Keep in mind, it would help if you could set the Mime-Type header of the response to `image/jpeg` too.

Comment: I thought the same thing could be possible and I like this idea, because realistically my http link and a normal image link are basically the same, the catch here is that there's basic authorization, so an access attempt like that would get immediately rejected by the server.

Answer (score 0):

With the additional information of basic authorization for your image, perhaps you should look into creating an **[HTTP Interceptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests)** to set the appropriate authorization headers.

This way, when you pull the image content (via AJAX), you can authorize the request properly. The image binary response you get could then be base64 encoded. Once that's done, you can insert it into the DOM with the following tag:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,[base64 encoded data]" />
```

---

Alternatively, you can try **URL Signing**.

When you use plain `<img src="https://example.com/image.src">`, you can't pass the authorization headers. Instead, you make POST request to the backend and retreive a temp link for the image and set this as image source of the tag.

---

Also, if this answer helps you, please accept it so others with similar issues may benefit from your feedback.